# SQL Query to Crystal Report

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

Need the results from this query:

```
SELECT  CAST(a.InvoiceDate AS DATE) InvoiceDate,
        COUNT(*) RecordCount
  FROM SalesOrder a
  JOIN IMSSalesExtractHistory b
    ON a.SlsOrdNbr = b.SlsOrdNbr
   AND a.OrdLnNbr = b.OrdLnNbr
   AND a.OrdLnSeqNbr = b.OrdLnSeqNbr
 WHERE b.SAFInsertDate > GETDATE()-2
GROUP BY CAST(a.InvoiceDate AS DATE)
ORDER BY CAST(a.InvoiceDate AS DATE)
```

to be replicated into my Crystal Report.

I have started this formula in the Formula Workshop window within Crystal Reports 2013 but it keeps giving me this error:

```
(
  SELECT DISTINCT CAST("SalesOrder"."InvoiceDate" AS DATE) InvoiceDate
    FROM "SalesOrder"
    JOIN "IMSSalesExtractHistory"
      ON "SalesOrder"."SlsOrdNbr" = "IMSSalesExtractHistory"."SlsOrdNbr"
     AND "SalesOrder"."OrdLnNbr" = "IMSSalesExtractHistory"."OrdLnNbr"
     AND "SalesOrder"."OrdLnSeqNbr" = "IMSSalesExtractHistory"."OrdLnSeqNbr"
   WHERE "IMSSalesExtractHistory"."FileDate" > {fn CURDATE()}
)
```

Error:

> ```
> ---------------------------
> SAP Crystal Reports
> ---------------------------
> Error in compiling SQL Expression :
> Failed to retrieve data from the database.
> Details: ADO Error Code: 0x80040e07
> Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server
> Description: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2016-05-25' to data type int.
> SQL State: 22018
> Native Error: 245 [Database Vendor Code: 245 ].
> ---------------------------
> OK   
> ---------------------------
> ```

I removed the COUNT(*) from the CS query because I was going to use the same code when I got it working and find the count for a new column within my report.

Looking for someone to help convert the initial SQL query so that it has no errors in Crystal Reports.

EDIT:
For reference, this is the result set I need in Crystal Report that I generated from the SQL script above.

```
 InvoiceDate    RecordCount
 2016-05-13     16074
 2016-05-14     2
 2016-05-15     4
 2016-05-16     27495
 2016-05-17     20023
 2016-05-18     18923
 2016-05-19     18944
```

Comment: Are you passed parameter? please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600435/database-connector-error

Comment: Have you tried to replace `DISTINCT CAST("SalesOrder"."InvoiceDate" AS DATE)` with `DateValue("SalesOrder"."InvoiceDate")`?

Answer (score 1):

Start crystal reports and make database connection.

instead of selecting tables select `add command` and paste this query

```
SELECT  CAST(a.InvoiceDate AS DATE) InvoiceDate,
        COUNT(*) RecordCount
  FROM SalesOrder a
  JOIN IMSSalesExtractHistory b
    ON a.SlsOrdNbr = b.SlsOrdNbr
   AND a.OrdLnNbr = b.OrdLnNbr
   AND a.OrdLnSeqNbr = b.OrdLnSeqNbr
 WHERE b.SAFInsertDate > GETDATE()-2
GROUP BY CAST(a.InvoiceDate AS DATE)
ORDER BY CAST(a.InvoiceDate AS DATE)
```

Now got to design and place the required columns in detail sectio.